# How to make css transform-origin property work in IE7 and IE8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have the following css rule:

```
transform-origin: 100% 50%;
```

How to make it work in IE7 and IE8? I was google'ing for 4 hours with no luck. Any help appreciated!

Comment: After a quick search, I came across this - http://someguynameddylan.com/lab/transform-origin-in-internet-explorer.php Check 3/4's way down the page for IE limitations and some workarounds are also shown within the page.

Comment: I've been looking at this website, but I don't need to apply rotate and skew as I'm rotating image with javascript. I believe this is a good solution, but don't understand how to remove rotate matrix...

Comment: I'm sorry but it is not very clear what you are asking for. Perhaps you could add more detail to your question using the edit button above to clarify.

Comment: I mean how to remove rotate and skew from this code -> `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11='0.7071',M12='-0.2479',M21='0.7071',M22='1.1663', sizingMethod='auto expand');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by making image double width as it was before and added `left: -300px`(half width of image). I know this is not the best way to do it, but anyway it works like it should do. Hope someone will find this answer helpful :)