# CSS3 feature doesn't work in IE in spite of adding -ms-

Tags: css, internet-explorer, stylesheet

This is the CSS I added to my website. it works in **firefox and Chrome** but doesn't work in **internet explorer**. **W3C** says these css features should be handled correctly in IE. IE can handle `transform-origin and transform-style` but not in here.

```
 a
{
color: #03c;
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
vertical-align: top;
-webkit-perspective: 600px;
-moz-perspective: 600px;
-o-perspective: 600px;
-ms-perspective: 600px;
perspective: 600px;
-webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
-moz-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
-o-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
-ms-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
perspective-origin: 50% 50%;}

a span
{
display: block;
position: relative;
padding: 0 2px;
-webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
-moz-transition: all 400ms ease;
-o-transition: all 400ms ease;
-ms-transition: all 400ms ease;
transition: all 400ms ease;
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
-moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
-o-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
-ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
transform-origin: 50% 0%;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform-style: preserve-3d;}

a:hover span 
{
background: #03c;
-webkit-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
-moz-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
-o-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
-ms-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
}

a span:after {
content: attr(data-title);
display: block;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
padding: 0 2px;
color: #fff;
background: #03c;
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
-moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
-o-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
-ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
transform-origin: 50% 0%;
-webkit-transform: translate3d( 0px, 105%, 0px ) rotateX( -90deg );
-moz-transform: translate3d( 0px, 105%, 0px ) rotateX( -90deg );
-o-transform: translate3d( 0px, 105%, 0px ) rotateX( -90deg );
-ms-transform: translate3d( 0px, 105%, 0px ) rotateX( -90deg );
transform: translate3d( 0px, 105%, 0px ) rotateX( -90deg );
}
```

Comment: "W3C says these css features should be handled correctly in IE." Really? Where does it say that? Also, a browser isn't magically going to support something just by adding the appropriate prefix to it.

Comment: IE 11. the latest version.
you enter the transform-origin and transform-style and see what W3C says about supported browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Internet Explorer 9** use the vendor prefix **-ms-**, although **-ms-** has been deprecated in **Internet Explorer 10 and later**.

Answer (score 0):

`ms-transform-origin` is supported in IE 9, `transform-origin` in IE10.
Lower Version do not support it at all.

Also have a look at [IE Dev Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj127313%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Edit:

Maybe have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13931835/how-to-make-css-transform-origin-property-work-in-ie7-and-ie8) on SO

Comment: i'm using IE 11.0.7 so it must support it, but try it yourself, that doesn't work in that case